# I am getting Error Code 2 when compiling C Program using Notepad++

Tags: nppexec

Using instructions I found on stackoverflow I am trying to use NppExec to compile my C files, run them, and show their output, all within Notepad++.

However when I try to use it I get this error message (see below) in Console.

Does anyone know how I fix this?

TIA
Roger

These are the instructions I followed:

I am using MinGW compiler.

Go to plugins->NppExec->Execute

paste this into there

NPP_SAVE

CD $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)

C:\MinGW32\bin\gcc.exe -g "$(FILE_NAME)"

a
(Remember to give above four lines separate lines.)

Now, give name, save and ok.

Restart Npp.

Go to plugins->NppExec->Advanced options.

Menu Item->Item Name (I have C compiler)

Associated Script-> from combo box select the above name of script.

Click on Add/modify and Ok.

Now assign shortcut key as given in first answer.

```
Current directory: C:\Users\Roger\Documents\Personal\UNB\F19\CS2263\Programs
C:\MinGW32\bin\gcc.exe -g "playStack.c"
; about to start a child process: "C:\MinGW32\bin\gcc.exe -g "playStack.c""
CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
The system cannot find the file specified.

a
; about to start a child process: "a"
CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Does this command `C:\MinGW32\bin\gcc.exe` exist on your system?

Comment: Hi Nicholas, it does now I kept working on the problem after I posted my question and was eventually able to get it working.